# Key is constantly pressed keyboard ghost key

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint

I have a key that is constantly pressed, even disconnecting the keyboard and changing it for another.

OS: Linux Mint 18.3

```
$ xev | grep 'keycode'
state 0x10, keycode 221 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
state 0x10, keycode 221 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
state 0x10, keycode 221 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
state 0x10, keycode 221 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
state 0x10, keycode 221 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
state 0x110, keycode 221 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
state 0x110, keycode 221 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
```

already try:

```
$ xmodmap -e 'keycode 221 = '
# And
$ xmodmap -e 'keycode 221 = NoSymbol'
```

When i press multiple times the `` ` `` key i get this:

```
``ῢ``ῢ``ῢῢῢ``ῢ``
```

The Linux Kernels i use are:

```
4.13.0.32
4.14.0
```

and the devices:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0458:0186 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Comment: First step is to use `evtest` on your keyboard device to find out if it comes from the kernel layer or X layer. For clarification: When you disconnect the keyboard, you don't get these events, when you connect a different keyboard, you get them again? Are these PS/2 or USB keyboards?

Comment: It happens all the time, with another keyboard, even when the keyboard is disconnected the event persists. Also restarting without keyboard. My keyboards are USB. Maybe it's kernel or something similar.

Comment: So my guess is that the event is coming from a different source, and not the keyboard. Run `evtest` as root, go through all devices, see if you can spot the device where it comes from.

Comment: / dev / input / event3: PEAQ WMI hotkeys

yeap, that one was creating the issue.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your solution should be an answer. Please read [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is the OP's solution originally published as an edit to the question. It should be an answer.

> Found that `/dev/input/event3: PEAQ WMI hotkeys` was causing
>   the error.
>
> ```
> $ sudo evtest
> No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
> Available devices:
> /dev/input/event0:    Power Button
> /dev/input/event1:    Power Button
> /dev/input/event2:    Video Bus
> /dev/input/event3:    PEAQ WMI hotkeys
> /dev/input/event4:    HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3
> /dev/input/event5:    HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7
> /dev/input/event6:    HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8
> /dev/input/event7:    HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
> /dev/input/event8:    HDA Intel PCH Line
> /dev/input/event9:    HDA Intel PCH Line Out
> /dev/input/event10:   KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse
> /dev/input/event11:   Logitech USB Keyboard
> /dev/input/event12:   Logitech USB Keyboard
> ```
>
> I stopped it with
>
> ```
> sudo rmmod peaq_wmi
> ```
>
> More info here:
>   https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work